# Activity consuming REST webservice using Volley library DOES NOT show layout loaded from XML (through setContentView())

Tags: android, android-layout, android-volley, android-xml, setcontentview

I want to have an Activity which consumes REST API using the Volley library, meanwhile showing a custom layout (written in XML layout file) on the screen.

So I wrote an Activity which, in its onCreate() calls `setContentView(R.layout.layout_file);` like usual. The *after that*, it consumes the REST API through Volley library (i.e. builds the Volley's `RequestQueue` object and then calls `requestQueueObject.add(requestObject)` on it).

The (relevant parts of the) code are given as follows.

**The problem is that *while* the data is being downloaded from the REST API, the layout loaded from the XML layout file using `setContentView()` (in `onCreate()` *before* consuming the REST web service) is NOT shown on the screen, and the screen remains blank. Then after that while, the layout defined in XML is shown momentarily, like for the blink of an eye, and then the next activity `AnotherActivity` is started.**

From the next Activity, if I press the back button, then the layout set in the XML is shown in the first Activity.

**How do I fix this problem?**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);

        PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, false);

        RequestQueue requestQueue = RequestQueueSingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getRequestQueue();
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                        ...
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        ...
                    }
                });

        requestQueue.add(request);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        startActivity(new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class));
    }
```

Comment: I think the issue here is because you call `Thread.sleep(5000);` from Main thread within the `onCreate` stage

Comment: @AleksandrMedvedev No, that is just a check I added to actually be sure that loading of layout from XML is actually delayed for as long as the REST API is consumed.

Comment: But why you don't started your activity in callback? If i'm right understand you, your are waiting wile response will be receiving?

Comment: @once2go No specific reason. Lemme try to run it after removing the `Thread.sleep()` and moving `startActivity()` call to the `onResponse()` callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should learn a bit more about Acitivty lifecycle and threads.

**First** - you don't see the Activity till the `onResume` stage. So while you make the thread sleep within the `onCreate` stage, `onResume` can't be reached (that's why you see the blank screen).

**Second** - you should not rely on timing to figure out when request is finished. Instead, start the desired activity within the callback methods (`Response.Listener<JSONObject>` and/or `Response.ErrorListener()`)

Answer (score 1):

onCreate you are making the thread sleep for 5sec hence this issue. You can solve the issue by making the following changes :

Replace this code :

```
try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        startActivity(new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class));
```

by:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(
                new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        startActivity(new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class));
                    }
                }, 5000);
```

> I'm guessing you are trying to achieve splash screen kind of
>   functionality, this solution should work for that.

Comment: Yes I am trying to add splash screen kind of functionality. But `Thread.sleep()` is just a check I added to be sure that the loading/display of layout from XML is delayed just for as long as REST API is being consumed. I AM comfortable with getting rid of the entire sleeping of the thread.

Comment: This rest api call is made is another thread hence it will not delay the launch of another activity. But yes if you launch your activity onResponse() of the API then the launch will be delayed till api response has been received.